# python Find the sum of all multiples of n below m

Tags: python

- Find the sum of all multiples of n below m
- Keep in Mind n and m are natural numbers (positive integers) m is
  excluded from the multiples
- sumMul(2, 9)   ==> 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20
- sumMul(3, 13)  ==> 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 = 30
- sumMul(4, -7)  ==> "INVALID"

---

I did sum of list using `range(n, m, n)` using `n` as step.
I also tried modulus to avoid range 3 args error.

I can pass many tests but cannot pass all of them.

I have tried lots of logic but to no avail. What I am doing wrong?

CODEWARS: https://www.codewars.com/kata/57241e0f440cd279b5000829/train/python

**MY CODE:**

```
def sum_mul(n, m):
    my_list = [number for number in range(n, m) if number % n == 0]
    sum_list = sum(my_list)
    if sum_list >= 1:
        return sum_list
    elif n == 0 and m == 0:
        return 'INVALID'
    elif n == m:
        return n - m
    elif n > m:
        return 'INVALID'
```

Comment: Hint: a) integer division is your friend; b) remember sum(1..n) == n*(n+1)/2; c) combine.

Comment: You need to use the mathematical formula, not a loop, so you won't get a TLE for large ranges.

Comment: @Barmar Not true.

Comment: You should do the input validation *before* the loop. And there's no need to make a list of the numbers, just use the generator in the `sum()` function.

Comment: Do you know which test cases failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one main problem, that is you should prevent the situation when `n==0` and you divide it in your list comprehension. It will raise `zero division error`. so you should check before the validation that n is not equal to zero.
Second thing is that you need to check whether `n or m` are negatives, as the exercise declared both n and m should be positives.

```
def sum_mul(n, m):
    if n==0:
        return 'INVALID'
    my_list = [number for number in range(n, m) if number % n == 0]
    sum_list = sum(my_list)
    if sum_list >= 1:
        return sum_list
    elif n < 0 and m <= 0:
        return 'INVALID'
    elif n == m:
        return n - m
    elif n > m:
        return 'INVALID'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails if `n == 0` as then the `number % n` checks in the list comprehension fail, so you should check that before trying to compute the sum. Also, you could use a `range` with `step`  and just do `sum(range(n, m, n))`. However, both ways might be too slow for some test cases with very large `m`.

You can do this in O(1) with the following observations:

1. there are `(m-1) // n` multiples of `n` below `m`
2. the sum of natural numbers from 1 to n is `n*(n+1)//2`

Combine those two to get the result.

Example for `sumMul(3, 13) ==> 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 = 30`:

- `(13-1) // 3 == 4` so we know there are 4 multiples of 3 below 13

  - those are `3 + 6 + 9 + 12 == 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)`
- with (2) we know `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 == 4*5//2 == 10`
- so the result is `10 * 3 == 30`

Putting that into code and handling the special cases is left as an exercise to the interested reader.

Comment: Given that the question is what they're doing wrong and that they're not failing because their solution is too slow, I don't think this is really an answer.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Added first sentence.

Comment: In fact you pretty much explicitly left out the answer as exercise :-P

Comment: `return sum(range(0, m, n)) if m > 0 < n else 'INVALID'` gets accepted. Looking at other people's solutions, simply using `sum(range(...))` seems by far the most popular way.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - cheers! worked perfect and I understand it (pretty much anyway :)). I was so close to what you did (although certainly not a one liner!) when using step in range but was failing on the logic of if n < m plus n == m.

Answer (score 0):

You should comprove all cases before call sum function.

Like this:

```
def sum_mul(n, m): 
    if n == 0 or m == 0:
        return 'INVALID'
    if n == m:
        return n - m
    if n<0 or m<0:
        return 'INVALID'
    
    my_list = [number for number in range(n, m) if number % n == 0]
    return sum(my_list)
```

In fact, you dont't need to create if elif structure because you are using returns, so next instruction after return not executed.

Comment: Because you check parameter before sum function

Comment: Have you comproved that it's working?

Comment: First of all, you always you should comprove that values that function received are ok to working

Comment: Sorry, i'd like to say "check". And indentation error... bro... you should press TAB button... OMG

Comment: Do you eat something and then see if it is expired? So, why do you calculate sum and then comprove if function values are ok??? Are you understand?

Comment: ive edited, now it's correct

Comment: Ok, now you have the solution, ive edited! it gets accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can just compute that result mathematically using integer divisions:

```
def sum_mul(n, m):
    if n<1 or n>m: return "INVALID"
    return m//n*(m//n+1)//2*n
```

First you get the number of multiple of `n` in `m` (which is merely dividing `m` by `n` ignoring the remainder) : `m//n`

Multiples of n will be nx1, nx2, nx3, ... up to the number of multiples.  Factorizing the sum of those by n we get: n(1+2+3+ ... m//n).

The sum of numbers from 1 up to a given number x is obtained by x(x+1)/2.  In this case x is the number of multiples `m//n`

Putting it all together we get n * x * (x+1) /2 where x is m//n, so:

```
n * (m//n) * (m // n + 1) // 2
```